# Error al encriptar con algoritmo afin

Tags: c++, encriptación

estoy usando cifrado afin con su formula
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
int main(){
 char p[100];
 char alf[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
 int a, b;

 printf("ingrese la palabra ");
 gets(p);
 printf("ingrese la constante de decimacion ");
 scanf("%i",&a);
 printf("ingrese la clave de cifrado ");
 scanf("%i",&b);

 int j;

 for(int i=0;i<strlen(p);i++){
  j=0;
   while(j<26){
      if(p[i]==alf[j]){
         p[i]= (a * alf[j] + b) % 26;
          j=26;
         }
        j++;
      }
   }

   printf("\nencriptacion:  \n");
   printf("\n %s",p);
  return 0;
   }
```

me imprime un simbolo raro, no encripta adecuadamente, no se cual sea el problema si la implementacion de la formula es correcta

Comment: ¿ Podrias poner un ejemplo de texto en claro y texto cifrado resultante o esperado ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin un ejemplo para comparar, no estoy seguro, pero creo que tu fallo está, precisamente, en tu implementación de la formula:

```
char alf[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
...
p[i]= (a * alf[j] + b) % 26;
```

Vemos lo que pasa si el carácter a cifrar es la letra `'a'`, la `constante de decimacion` es `1`, y la `constante de desplazamiento` es 1:

> ( 1 * alf[0] + 1 ) % 16
>   ( 1 * 113 + 1 ) % 16 // ( el código ASCII de 'a' es 113)
>   114 % 16
>   2

Y la grafía correspondiente al código ASCII `2` no existe; es un código de control.

Ahora, cambiemos tu formula a esto otro:

```
p[i]= alf[(a * j + b) % 26];
```

> ( 1 * 0 + 1 ) % 16
>   1 % 16
>   1

Que nos daría como resultado `alf[1]`, que es el caracter `'b'`.

Comment: muchas gracias despues de revisar el codigo efectivamente ese era el error, ahora corre perfectamente, muchas gracias